# Can mechanize for Ruby filter the contents of a <select> by class?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Sorry, but I didn't find the documentation enlightening at all. Basically, I am trying to iterate through a  where some options are not valid. The ones I want have 'class="active"'. Can I do that with mechanize? Here's what I have so far:

```
class Scraper
def init
    mech = Mechanize.new
    page = mech.get('url')


    #Now go through the <select> to get product numbers for the different flavors
    form = page.form_with(:id => 'twister')
    select = form.field_with(:name => 'dropdown_selected_flavor_name')
    select.options.each do |o| 
        if (o.text != "")
            value = o
        end
        productNumber = trim_pn(value.to_s[2..12])
        puts productNumber
    end
end

#Checks validity of product number and removes excess characters if necessary
    def trim_pn(pn)
        if (pn[0] == ",")
            pn = pn[1..-1]
        end
        return pn
    end
end

p = Scraper.new
p.init
```

All that does is grabs the product number and removes some extra info that I don't want. I thought replacing the .each do with this:

```
select.options_with(:class => 'active').each do |o| 
    if (o.text != "")
        value = o
    end
end
```

But that throws "undefined method 'dom_class' for Mechanize:Form:Option blah blah." Is there are different way I should be approaching this?

Comment: The easy way is to use iterate it with css: `page.search('option.active')`

Comment: I'm having difficult making that work. Is #search a mechanize method?

Comment: Mechanize::Page, yes.